# I'm an American citizen who wishes to fly from Tijuana to Guadalajara. Can I actually complete this flight solely with a U.S. Passport Card?

Tags: air-travel, passports, us-citizens, mexico

A few years ago, I travelled with my father from Tijuana to Guadalajara after using the CBX to get into Mexico from San Diego. At that point, I only had a U.S. passport card and NO passport book, and they allowed us to fly within Mexico with no hiccups. People close to me claim that I need a passport book since I am technically a foreigner flying domestically in Mexico, and I haven't found much information online stating that a U.S. passport card will suffice to fly within Mexico. Anywho, my cousins and I have travelled from Tijuana to other parts of Mexico with only a U.S. passport card for years, and basically I'm wondering if this is allowed or if we've been extremely lucky. I'm only an American citizen for more context.

Comment: I believe that officially the airlines require foreigners on domestic flights in Mexico to use a passport (book) as ID, however in reality it will come down to what happens on the day.  More than likely they'll accept it as valid ID and let you fly, but know that there is the risk that they may not.

Comment: @Midavalo But you can enter Mexico by land, *and* obtain an FMM with a passport card. So in theory Mexico is satisfied that you are who you say you are with just the passport card.

Comment: @PeterM That is allowed for the **border zone** only. So in praxis you are breaking the Mexican immigration laws when leaving the boder zone with only the passport card.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Note I said "obtain an FMM".  That allows you to leave the border zone

Comment: @PeterM See my answer that quotes the rules in the FMM application form.

Answer (score 1):

Just an anecdotal evidence: as a   French citizen and US  lawful permanent resident, I was able to board a plane from TIJ to MEX airport with my US driving license only. No questions asked, I didn't have to  convince anyone, everybody seems fine with it. Therefore I'm guessing a U.S. passport card is ok too (preferably to be confirmed with someone else).

Comment: This is not evidence at all that it is allowed, only that the checks were sloppy. Any further checks inside Mexico could lead to problems.

Comment: @MarkJohnson  The question is only about the flight. My US driving license was enough to  satisfy several front desk employees and  several security personnels at the airport, so it seems rather commonplace to accept it.

Comment: The question is about leaving the border zone with a passport card and whether it is allowed. The answer is no, the immigration laws of Mexico doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 1):

No, the passport card may only be used in the border zone.

> [Instituto Nacional de Migración - Forma Migratoria Múltiple](https://www.inm.gob.mx/fmme/publico/en/solicitud.html)
> ...
> The applicant is aware that the **card passport** (Tarjeta Pasaporte) **can only be used in the border crossings by land and for visiting the border zone**; it might [may] **not be used to travel to the territory of the Mexican Republic or used for international air trips**.
> ...